# Is ranked and "normal" (quick play) MMR separate?

Tags: overwatch

I play almost exclusively quick play, but I did do some ranked matches just to get placed to see where I end up. As far as I can tell, my opponents in ranked were about the same skill level as the people I was facing in quick play. Since I did so few ranked matches, I was wondering if my quick play MMR (or whatever the equivalent is in Overwatch) was separate from my ranked MMR.

Comment: I've found a lot of forum posts about this, but no solid answers.  From one [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4qhz93/does_quick_play_mmr_affect_competitive_mmr/), it looks like the answer is yes its separate.

Comment: I would guess its separate, having experience in other games (i.e Dota2)

Comment: Part of me wants to say yes, because I'm a diamond player and played against a top 500 in QP yesterday, but at the same time I feel like I've seen something that said the hidden MMR was used for both.

Comment: By best guess would be that your first games in competitive would try to emulate what you currently see in quick play. But from there onwards, the MMR (or SR in competitive) should be completly differenciated from quick play. But please note that Blizzard is messing around a lot these days with the competitive environment. Sometimes for the best... And more often for the worse :/ http://imgur.com/a/cYWwb

Comment: Yes, two days ago my 2800~ team was matched against a 3800~ team. /1000/ point difference. It wasn't even worth leaving our spawn.

Comment: @ZealousHypocrites On the bright side, you can't have lost much ranking.

Comment: We lost 4 points. Those 4 points we had just gained in the previous match. The previous match was stressful as hell (but evenly matched), and we had to pull everything together just to /draw/ the game. After ALL that work, time, energy, and stress for nearly 20 minutes...and the game just TAKES it back. So that's 30 minutes down the drain because of a single matchmaking, in a night where we have maybe 90 minutes to play. Not much of a bright side... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

This became abundantly clear if you played QuickPlay in the off season between Competitive seasons 1 and 2 and again between seasons 2 and 3.

Why?  Because people who played exclusively Competitive were queuing with the same QuickPlay MMR they had before they switched over to playing Competitive, meaning that they were often being matched against teams whose players were considerably worse at the game.