# How to reset MMR to escape Bronze tier (bottom 1%)?

Tags: overwatch

For most of the 3rd and 4th seasons, I sat just bellow Silver (900 - 1300 SR). Of course I think I should be higher, but that's a fair place for me to be, and I enjoy playing at that level.

Over the last few nights I had a very long loss streak and am now around 700 SR. At this level I've had multiple games where Mercys refuse to heal and just shoot, you can win a game with 6 attack heros, and people are so toxic that I often remove myself from voice chat. I play tanks and healers, and so I enjoy the game most when my team is playing together. Right now, my enjoyment of the game is shot.

I'm worried that I now have a terribly low MMR and will continue to place at this level next season.

**Question: Given the way the SR / MMR system works, what things can I do to increase my chances of placing higher next season?**

Like, for example, would it help if I stuck to Quick Play for a while to up my MMR before doing the Season 5 Qualifying Matches? Should I create a new account to get a clean MMR?

I'm aware that long term, I should probably go to Looking-For-Group sites and find a community, but at the moment "700 SR healer/tank" won't get any clicks.

---

*Note that I am **not** looking for gameplay tips, I'm specifically asking about "resetting" my SR / MMR.*

Comment: Resetting MMR could only really be done by creating a new battle.net ID.

Comment: I strongly suspect QuickPlay MMR is ignored for comp season placements unless maybe it's your first season. I'm only 2100 SR in comp (down from 61 in Season 1), in part because all I do is placements every season so I seem to be steadily dropping every season due to how that works, but in QP I'm always matched against a minimum of diamonds and quite often GMs and Top 500s. There's definitely a huge difference between my rating in the two modes but I suspect after placements next season I'll be high silver/low gold (since placements usually put you a little lower than your end-of-season SR)

Comment: It's worth realising that if the Mercy's on _your_ team are playing _incorrectly_ (disclaimer: I've never played), then it's likely they're doing the same on the other team. What I mean to say is if the players on _your_ team are _noobs_, then it's the same on the other team. This means it should overall give you an advantage if you're indeed better than you're current rank. Not an answer, but I'd imagine you should just keep patient and try to ignore the number

Comment: @Tas I follow you in principle. But at least IMO having a bad team effects some heroes and playstyles a lot more. Some of characters are basically useless with an awful team. Others dont really care.

Comment: I know you didn't ask for gameplay tips, but as a general rule the less your team is playing as a team the less effective the tank and healer roles become. If you're better than the average bronze player you should easily be able to escape bronze playing offensive characters.

Comment: "You can fix the matchmaking, but you can't fix people".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Self-answer:** In the year since posting, I've never been able to get above 900 SR again. Last week I bought a second copy of the game (aka new account), ground out 15 hours of quick play to level 25, went 3-7-0 on my Competitive Placement Matches, and ranked **Silver with 1793 SR**. Higher than the career high on my first account.

---

**Extra context:** I came from MMOs and Final Fantasy-type games and Overwatch was my first ever FPS. When I did my initial placement matches in July 2016, a Bronze rating was probably fair. In the 2 years since, I have watched / read a lot of guides, and become a big fan of Overwatch League pro play. There is no doubt that I am a much better player now.

**Takeaways**:

- The Placement Matches between Competitive Seasons are total garbage since they doesn't actually reset your Skill Rating.
- The game's rating system does not account for big jumps in player skill after their initial placement matches.
- The "Bronze trap" is real. A strong DPS might be able to carry themself out, but the lack of teamwork in the bottom 1% of players makes it very hard for a Tank / Healer to have a consistent impact on the game.

Comment: Comments for downvotes please?

Answer (score 33):

[Ranked and quick play MMR is separate](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/294673/145980). The only way to truly reset your MMR is to buy the game again on a new account, which will set your MMR to be whatever the average rank is.

However, I strongly advise against doing this. If you dropped down to 700 SR, chances are you probably belong somewhere around that level, plus or minus a couple hundred SR. (Not trying to be rude, just stating how the system is supposed to work.) It might be tough, but if your actual skill level is higher than that, you should eventually climb out on your own. Buying a new account risks you paying extra money just to go through the exact same frustration when you drop lower again.

At the start of every new season, there is a soft-reset of all player's ranks (normalized to the average player rank, which I think is somewhere in silver or gold). I don't know if this also affects MMR, but it should give you a chance to place higher than you might have gotten in the previous season.

Loss streaks happen, and the matchmaking system realizes this. Chances are your MMR is probably not all that heavily affected. You're probably still playing with people of a similar skill level as before, but because your visible rank is lower, you focus more on how "bad" your teammates are *now* as opposed to how they played before the loss streak.

Even if your MMR is lower now... that's how it's supposed to work. The matchmaking system tries to even everyone out to an approximately 50% win/loss ratio. Trying to get around this system is just asking for frustration.

Comment: I did not downvote, but this answer seems extremely condescending and incorrect.  Saying _"loss streaks do not heavily affect your MMR"_ is obviously false - OP lost >200 points in one streak, and I've personally had >400.  Also saying _"chances are you probably belong in [the bottom 1%]"_ is extremely rude, and also likely incorrect.  Even the best players have difficulty getting out of MMR Hell (see my answer) due to how heavily team-based the game is.  The bottom 1% consists largely of trolls and small children, which is certainly not _"people of a similar skill level as [in Silver]"_.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft SR is simply a visible representation of your general skill level, but it is NOT the same thing as your MMR. You will never be able to see your actual MMR. If you're gaining more SR on wins than you're losing for losses, then your MMR is higher than your current rank, and vice versa. If the SR change is about equal for both wins and losses, then your MMR is about equal to your rank. If OP can't climb out of the rank he's in, his MMR will normalize to that rank and then by definition that's where he belongs based on his skill level. That's how the MMR system works.

Comment: Also, "even the best players have difficulty getting out of MMR Hell" is straight up false. If it were true, streamers would not purposely fail their placements and lower their SR just so they can do a "bronze to grandmaster" stream. It's been done hundreds of times, not just in OW but in many other games as well. "MMR Hell" isn't a specific rank - it's wherever your own personal skill level plateaus, which is where you will need to rely more and more on your teammates. For some people, that's bronze; for others, it's platinum or diamond or even higher.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - streaks don't have as much of an impact now, not since the uprising patch.

Comment: And if you take offense to me saying that OP might belong at the rank he is now, I'm sorry, I truly don't mean to be condescending or rude. I'm merely trying to explain how the MMR system is designed. I would have said the same thing if he had complained about dropping from diamond to plat.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't soft-reset your rank to gold every season. I've seen previous-season GMs have like 2 wins 8 losses in placements and still end up GM or high masters. I've gone 8 wins 2 losses and always come out about 100-200 SR than I ended the last season. 

I mean, no one knows for sure, but a lot of people feel strongly it plops you right around your old SR, plus or minus about 200 points. Usually minus. And I can't find the source, but I'm pretty certain I've seen Blizzard posts stating that your first 50 or so games get a SR boost for wins to "catch you up" to your real SR.

Comment: @MageXy: Bronze is everything below 1500.  There is a HUGE difference between 1400 and 700.  And I never said it's not possible to climb out of 700 - of course it's still possible, but it's (counter-intuitively) **significantly** more effort to climb out of 700 than 1400 by yourself.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft It's **never** harder to climb out of a lower MMR in any PVP game. There's a reason even mid-elo players just stomp through lower ratings, mainly because they have the game knowledge the low-elo players lack. People can escape extremely low ratings in shooters by simply knowing the map. As you progress further you have to improve more and more aspects of your gameplay/game knowledge. The higher you get the harder it is to improve. If you play somewhat decent in a 700 game you will win climb pretty fast (given the player can play better than the avg 700 player).

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft MMR hell doesn't actually exist...  It's just a made up theory that is been thoroughly debunked by this point. It is different for each player but really just means 'this is where you belong' when someone says they are stuck in MMR hell.

Comment: @dphil A lot of people use "MMR Hell" to refer to "getting stuck at a rank I feel is too low for me".  That's what you're talking about, but it's not what I'm talking about.  I'm talking about the very VERY bottom ranks being significantly harder to get out of than other ranks, which is absoluely a real effect.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft The mathematics behind it actually supports what I say and fully debunks your point.  There are 4 players on your team that can potentially ruin the game for you if they are doing something stupid or trolling whereas there are 5 players on the other team that can potentially do the same thing for their team.  ELO hell isn't a real thing outside of being an imaginary excuse.

Comment: @MageXy bronze-to-grandmaster is only possible if you already are at the level of a grandmaster.

Comment: The thing about MMR that people _really_ don't like to accept in games is that, usually, the MMR you're at is close to the MMR you _should_ be at. However, there is some inertia in the system, and it can be a slog to adjust it when it actually is off by a small-medium margin. The way to improve it is to accept that there will be losses, and to find out what you can do to improve your chances of winning every game.

Comment: @dphil Or worse: they can straight up abandon you, and you're stuck on a 1-2 vs. 6 match. No matter how useless your team is, they are (at least) making them waste time by making the enemy kill them.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I'm not really sure what you are trying to say here.  Did you just comment and ignore everything I said except that ELO hell doesn't exist?

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga Yes, I know. That's exactly my point. If your actual skill level is higher than your current rank, you will eventually climb. Once you've stopped climbing, you've reached that peak of your natural abilities and you now have to invest time and effort into learning how to get better. Most people don't want to spend the effort doing that - they would rather keep winning without working harder for it. Once people are at this level, they blame "MMR Hell" for preventing them from climbing... but no such thing exists. It's all on them.

Comment: @MageXy I just don't think the difficulty is linearly proportional to skill level. I feel like it's more of an exponential relationship. GMs do really well because they're exponentially more skilled than the rank below them, etc. Which I guess means we're not in disagreement.

Comment: I wish the part about "you probably belong there" were true, my friend. It's not. You see, on my main account, I was in middle bronze for the longest time, getting 3 gold medals in 8 out of 10 matches at least, sometimes 50% to 75% kill participation (!), literally carrying matches, and yet the bitter reality is that Blizzard's system gives you more than 5 unwinnable matches out of every 10. I was logging & monitoring. This is not an opinion, but a statistic. I kid you not, more than 5 out of 10 matches (5.35 to be exact) were impossible to win due to matchmaking.

Comment: To continue, through all that mid-bronze main account stuff, I was Platinum on a completely different account. I was NEVER boosted/carried on that other account. I promise you, Blizzard's system did think the guy with SR 800 is the same guy with SR 2500. That's 1700 SR points of difference!!! So no, they probably don't belong in bronze. Nobody who consistently gets 3 gold medals, including objective kills, belongs in bronze, my friend. It's just a deeply messed up matchmaking and placement system.

Comment: @Rok: Medals are the most misused metric in the game. They do *not* tell you how good you are doing  overall - they are telling you how good your are doing *relative to the performance of the rest of your team*. It's easy to get a gold medal for 3 elims if the rest of your team doesn't kill anything. Doesn't mean you did all that great though. [See this graph for for an example of what I mean.](https://i.imgur.com/XpIZP51.png).

Comment: @MageXy And 50% to 75% elimination participation, basically carrying games, also doesn't tell you how well you did? And 24 average eliminations per 10 min compared to 26 by top players in the ladder also doesn't tell you how well you do? As Doomfist says, "Spare me the commentary." You, people, are willing to even use stats to justify bringing down skilled players to your level; I don't know why, but it's not working on me. I know that I belong at least in Masters with my current gameplay & skill, and the system keeps me in Silver and Gold by design just to make me player longer.

Comment: @Rok You keep telling yourself that. If what you say is true, how do the masters/top 500 consistently get multiple smurf accounts up to the same rank, over and over? Shouldn't they get stuck in gold/plat/diamond on at least one of them? I myself am a FPS newbie (OW is my first competitive FPS game), yet I've gotten myself to plat multiple seasons in a row, despite landing in gold and silver after placements. The reason you're not climbing is because your playstyle (whatever that may be) is not conducive to climbing.

Comment: @MageXy They can consistently raise their smurf accounts because they  mostly play with the same people! I thought everyone understood this by now. If you want to climb, you just need to find compatible teammates and stop solo queuing. It's really that simple. And it's super easy for famous Twitch streamers and YouTubers to find compatible, skilled teammates obviously. You can find confirmation for this from Stylosa, for example, who subscribed to your theory of "you probably belong there, elo hell is a myth" just a year ago until he actually tried solo queuing, and now tells the bitter story.

Comment: @MageXy And you can debunk your own linked graph if you just think analytically and logically for a few seconds. That dotted red line labeled "Damage needed to make an impact" is obviously arbitrary, at least partially. Isn't it? Of course, it is. There is one major non-arbitrary factor that determines the height of that line, though, and that's the skill of your opponents, how well they counter ultimates, absorb & heal damage, that sort of thing. On the other hand, the more you shorten the orange bar & lengthen the blue bar, the more this means "You" are really skilled. So why no "impact"?

Comment: @MageXy No "impact" because Blizzard's matchmaking system has the control and ability, especially in solo queue, to raise that dotted line to literally impossible levels for one player to fulfill. Blizzard's matchmaking system can put skilled opponents against you, thus raising the red dotted line a lot, while giving you low-skill teammates, thus shortening the orange bar as much as possible, thus leaving your "blue bar" mission quite literally Mission Impossible. Something that even an aimbotter can't accomplish in a game like Overwatch with all the shields and so.

Comment: @Rok The matchmaking system tries to put you in matches where you have a 50% chance of winning. If you win more often than lose, you will face stronger and stronger opponents (the dotted line is raised). If you continue to win, you will gain more SR than you lose, and you will climb, even if you lose a few matches. Whenever you lose, the dotted line goes down a few notches, and the next match you will face slightly weaker players. If you lose a lot, the dotted line drops faster (as does your SR) while the system tries to match you to a 50% win rate skill level.

Comment: The entire system is based on playing a ton of games. Mathematically, if a single player could play an infinite number of games on an infinite number of accounts, a vast majority of them will end up at nearly the same SR. In real life, people don't play an infinite number of games, so it may look like the system is lopsided *in some cases* - but for most of the playerbase, it works as expected. However, you don't hear about the millions of normal cases - the only people that come online to complain are the outliers, so the "vocal minority" makes it look like the system is broken when it isn't.

Comment: If you want to continue discussing this, let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64374/discussion-between-mage-xy-and-rok) so we don't clog up the comments section.

Answer (score 25):

Your best option is to **find some players who are also stuck in the bottom ranks, and group up with them**.  Find people with mics so you can coordinate your attacks/defense over Discord or in-game voice chat.  Even if they are not very good, having consistent teammates and even a small amount of coordination should easily get you all back into the 1000's.

---

Why is having a group so important? In Overwatch *(and many other team-based games)*, the ranks at the bottom 1%(-ish) are known as *MMR Hell* - the skills of players varies so wildly, you're just as likely to get a troll teammate who's trying to lose, or a 5-year-old mashing on the controller, as you are a decent teammate.

People claim "over enough games it will even out", but they're forgetting that people often group up, which screws up the balance.  Eg. if there's a group of 5 and you're solo-queueing, you have a 1/7 chance of being on their team, and 6/7 chance of being against them.  And given that they're likely not deliberately grouping with trolls/5-year-olds, you have a much higher chance of losing.

Thus, getting out of the lowest ranks by yourself takes significantly more effort than at higher ranks, no matter how good you are *(and unlike many other team-games, in Overwatch even the best players can't carry an entire team by themselves)*.  Because of this, "playing a lot of games" is not a good option.  You will eventually get out of MMR Hell, but depending on your luck it could take a *long* time.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58672/discussion-on-answer-by-blueraja-danny-pflughoeft-how-to-reset-mmr-to-escape-b).

Answer (score 3):

Placement matches are not a fresh start, they're based off your final placement in the previous season. There is no way to "reset MMR", your only chance is to win more games than you lose.

Comment: There is also the different resets they've implemented in each season. Season 2 was a really hard reset to fix that first ranking system. Season 3 had next to no reset, and Season 4 was a soft reset. I imagine the next season will have something similar

Comment: This. They use the placement matches to adjust the MMR and tweak it however they see fit, for doing this in the middle of the season would raise tons of complains. I expect season 5 placement matches to be just that again, you get exactly the MMR you'd have had in-season for winning/losing these matches, +/- adjustments if they think to many / too few people are placed in certain ranks.